# Theoretical property of homogeneous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering if the following property is true:

"If $f(x,y)$ is an homogeneous function with degree $m$, is $F(x,y)=f(f(x,y),f(x, y))$
also homogeneous?"
Because I jnow that the partial derivative of $f$ is an homogeneous function of degree $m-1$ but I don't know really how to check it in this case or find a counterexample. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of "homogeneous function?" Can you check that $F$ satisfies it?

Comment: u need to start from the definition of homogeneous function.$F(tx,ty)=f(f(tx,ty),f(tx,ty))=f(t^{m}f(x,y),t^{m}f(x,y))=t^{m^{2}}F(x,y)$

Comment: Oh, it's true!! I have thought of using additional properties but it was quite simple with the definiton :).Thanks!

Comment: @Jochen it is not a product , homogeneity means,that for every real number $s$,;$f(sx,sy)=s^{m}f(x,y)$, apply this for $s=t^{m}$ .